# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Installed Ubuntu on latest Virtualbox 4.3.20. After login, I can only see blank screen. I am completely new to Ubuntu. What do I do?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, screen

Installed latest Virtualbox 4.3.20 on my Windows 8.1 machine.
Then downloaded and installed latest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .iso file from ubuntu.com

After set up and all, the machine asked to restart. After the restart, and logging in, the display only shows the default purple-red wallpaper. No icons, no menu, no status bar, nothing. Only the cursor is visible. What do I do?

I am completely new to Ubuntu / Linux. Please Help.

Configs: 
core-i3 4030U
4 GB RAM
1TB HDD
Windows 8.1

"Virtual Machine" configs:
1 CPU (out of total 4)
1802 MB RAM
64 GB disk space
32 MB display memory

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot? Depending on the DE you chose (most likely Unity), the desktop may be rather empty immediately after install. `ctrl-alt-t` will open a shell (verify this works). The fact that you could login from a graphical shell means the DM is installed properly. Otherwise open up ubuntu software center by typing `software-center` into the terminal you opened with `ctrl-alt-t` and start installing whatever you need.

Comment: Ubuntu/Unity will need >= 256 MB of video memory. You then also may want to [install the guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

Comment: I do not know how to post screenshots here. However, I have one here: https://www.quora.com/Ubuntu-on-Virtualbox-the-screen-goes-blank-after-sign-in-No-icons-no-status-bar-only-the-wallpaper-is-visible-How-do-I-solve-this @crasic

Comment: At the very least, you can try basically what is suggested on quora, open a terminal (`ctrl-alt-t`) and start nautilus by typing `nautilus` and see if you get a windows-explorer looking window to browse the hard-drive. You can also attempt to avoid loading the graphics-heavy components by selecting ubuntu-classic (or gnome-2d) when logging in (click on the little ubuntu sign next to your user name on the login screen and it will give you options) to check if it boots fine into that.

Comment: No, ctrl-alt-t is not working. @crasic